# Phase difference at a point due to the geometrical path difference and phase difference at source

Tags: optics, waves

[image]

I think the picture explains the problem I have pretty well.
Basically I want find the net phase difference between rays AP and BP at P.
A and B are point sources.
B leads by phase difference of y at source.
Geometrical phase difference is x.

The net phase difference at P should x+y or x-y, but I don't understand which one.
I think it should x-y because B leads by y at source an A leads due to the gpd by x.

But textbooks add the phase difference due to the 2 factors.
Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I explained the configuration with more detail. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Next time don't add a picture to describe text, or variables. The right text should have been written down with only the triangle left in the picture. Becasue it's hard to tell from your handwriting. But I'll try to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function of the light ray is $f(wt-kx)$ or $f(wt+kx)$ might have to do with the incorrect relative sign.

If the first case is the one you had, then $AP > BP$ means that the phase from A is smaller, so B has a bigger phase due to distance, and also due to the phase he already had, giving: $x+y$!

---

Edit: But it could be anything, it depends on the choice of your professor in how the x phase contributes. The problem is really not complete, it might be your fault for not writing all the things you really knew from it, or from professors that assume such things as trivial, and sometimes skip things that are actually necessary to understand the problem the first time you see it.

Comment: The question that I was working with was itself vague. You are right, we were supposed to assume the general equation to be with a -kx as a convention, but it wasnt specified.

Comment: Everything clear then, gl!